# jQuery wait for first animation to finish before starting next one

Tags: jquery, loops, callback

Need to make DOM elements fade in one after another with jQuery, obviously i need loop as i have 20 elements, i don't know proper way to make loop in jQuery  so i did following.

However callback does not work properly, all elements fade in at same time, it supposed to wait for first animation to finish and only then run **animate_element()** again.

If there's better way to do it i'd like to know it, however i also wonder why below code does not work?

```
$('div').css("display", "none");
$('div').addClass("needs_animation");

function animate_element(){
    if ( $("div[class='needs_animation']:first").length ) {

        $("div[class='needs_animation']:first").removeClass("needs_animation");

        $("div[class='needs_animation']:first").fadeIn(2000, animate_element());

    }
}

animate_element();
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m7PWT/1/**

EDIT: Fixed thanks to John S response, however i used my own code even though its performance not the best, as its more clear for me at this point.

```
$('div').css("opacity", "0");
$('div').addClass("needs_animation");

function animate_element(){
    if ( $("div[class='needs_animation']").length ) {

        $("div[class='needs_animation']:first").animate({opacity:1}, 100, function() {
            $("div[class='needs_animation']:first").removeClass("needs_animation");
            animate_element()
        });

    }
}

animate_element();
```

**Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m7PWT/6/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close with what you had. You just had two mistakes:

(1) You should have stored off the result of `$("div[class='needs_animation']:first")` in a variable. Not only is that more efficient, but in this case, you do not want to re-execute that after you remove the class because you will get a different result.

(2) When you supplied the callback function to `.animate()`, you should not have included the parentheses after it. You were actually calling it.

Here is what the code could look like:

```
$('div').css("opacity", "0");
$('div').addClass('needs_animation');

(function animate_element(){
    var $div = $('div.needs_animation:first');
    if ($div.length) {
        $div.removeClass('needs_animation');
        $div.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000, animate_element);
    }
})();
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ngKH/)

And one more thing: When selecting elements by class, use `'div.needs_animation'`, rather than `'div[class="needs_animation"]'`. The former will work even if the elements have more than one class.

Comment: @user3185872 - That's a good question. I didn't look at your code too closely at first, but I have been missing with it. There's one issue I see right away. You repeat `$("div[class='needs_animation']:first")`, rather than store it in a variable. That's not just a performance issue; It will have a different result after you remove the class. But just making that change still doesn't get it to work.

Comment: Makes sense thanks, its my first day with jQuery, but i am coming from PHP background.

Comment: @user3185872 - I was delayed for a while, but I figured out why your code did not work. See my updated answer. I changed the code in my answer to be more like what you originally had, which was actually quite good. You had a pretty good idea of how it should work to begin with.